# RegEx: Disallow strings in a sub catchgroup

Tags: python, regex

I still have a working regex pattern. Now I found a new case that isn't catched
My first solution does interfere with the previous cases.

I want to extract three parts of a string. I'm using Python3 for this and also tested arround on regex101.com.

Here is an example input string:

```
foo:bar][bluered
```

The resulting substrings should be `foo`, `bar` and `blured`.
I can handle this via that RegEx pattern (Python3).

```
^(?:([^:]+):)?(.*?)(?:]\[(.*))?$
```

Let me describe in my own words

- The first substring (`foo`) before the `:` is optional. That pattern also works with input `bar][bluered`.
- The second and third should be there and divided via `][`.

## Problem

Now the problem case where the first substring is missing and the third substring contain a `:`.

```
bar][blue:red
```

The pattern gives me resulting substrings `bar][blue` and `red` and the third is ignored. The *expected* result here is an empty first substring and then `bar` as second and `blue:red` as third.

## My approach

I added a check for `][`:

```
^(?:]\[([^:]+):)?(.*?)(?:]\[(.*))?$
    ^^^
```

This does catch input like `bar][blue:red` the way I need it. But the *problem* now is that the `:` between first and second substring is ignored:

```
foo:bar][blue:red
```

results in an empty first substring and `foo:bar` as second and `blue:red` as third.
I do need `foo` as first, `bar` as second and `blue:red` as third.

Now I'm a bit confused how to go further. I think somehow I need to ignore the `:` after the `][` in the third group even when there is no `:` between the first and second group (before the `][`).

I need to find a solution that works for both types of input strings

```
bar][blue:red
foo:bar][blue:red
```

*EDIT*: Tried a lookahead but doesn't work. It should "mean" match `:` only if it is in front of a `][`.

```
^(?:([^:]+(?=\]\[)):)?(.*?)(?:]\[(.*))?$
          ^^^^^^^^^
```

But maybe it is the right direction?

Comment: Can you try `^(?:([^:]+):)?(.*?)(?:(?<=\]\[)|(?<=:))(\w+(?::\w+)?)$
`

Comment: Thanks for reply. No it doesn't work for `foobar][blue:red` as input.

Comment: Couldn't you use `split(r'[]:[]+')` or `split(r':|\]\[')` instead of matching?

Comment: Yes I could. But I would like to prevent non-regex problem.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert that `][` should not occur in the first group, using a negative look ahead assertion on every position in the first capture group:

```
^(?:((?:(?!]\[)[^:])*):)?(.*?)(?:]\[(.*))?$
```

Answer (score 2):

For ease of explanation, a "special" character is defined to be one of `:[]`.

```
^               # At the beginning of the string/line
(?:             # Match an
  ([^:[\]]+)    #                   group consisting of 1+ non-special characters
  :             #                                       followed by a colon
)?              #          optional
([^:[\]]*?)     # then 0+ non-special characters, lazily,
(?:             # then another          group, consisting of
  ]\[(.*)       #                                            literal '][' and 0+ characters
)?              #              optional
$               # followed by the end of string/line.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nPaxRa/2).

If you want to match `foo:bar:baz:boo`, the second capturing group should be changed to `([^[\]\n]*?)` (no colon):

```
^(?:([^:[\]]+):)?([^[\]]*?)(?:]\[(.*))?$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nPaxRa/3).

Comment: I can confirm that your solution also works in all my productive/real test cases. I just acepted trincot's solution because it is (for me) easier to understand. Would be great if both of you could compare the two solutions.

Comment: @buhtz They are basically the same, it's just that I prefer `[^:[\]]` to `(?:(?!]\[)[^:])` since the former doesn't have any lookarounds and therefore works with less steps (you can compare them on regex101).

Answer (score 1):

Based on provided description, I believe simple

```
^(?:(.*):)?(.*)\]\[(.*)$
```

should suffice.

It'll find last `][` and `:` before it (if exists).

| input | first match | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo:bar][bluered | foo | bar | bluered |
| foo:bar][blue:red | foo | bar | blue:red |
| foobar][blue:red |  | foobar | blue:red |
| abr][red |  | abr | red |
| foo:bar][blue:red][sdsd:df | foo:bar][blue | red | sdsd:df |

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Zd7qZE/1)

Comment: The third part (`][` and thereon) is also optional. See OP's original regex.

Comment: @InSync, my judgement based on this: "The second and third should be there and divided via `][`"

Comment: You are right the third part is also optinal. But I forget this and didn't understand my own regex. So i forget to mention this explicte. But thanks for your answer which I also learn from.